# Custom menu wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

```
                     <ul>
                        <li><hr class="menu-dotted-line"/></li>
                        <li class="menu-button-bg">
                            <div class="menu-button">HOME</div>
                            <div class="menu-button-desc">back to hompage</div>
                            <div></div>
                        </li>
                        <li><hr class="menu-dotted-line"/></li>
                        <li class="menu-button-bg hide-sub-menu">
                            <div class="menu-button">PORTFOLIO</div>
                            <div class="menu-button-desc">view our work</div>
                            <div></div>
                        </li>
                        <li><hr class="menu-dotted-line"/></li> 
                    </ul>
```

Is there any way to implement this code into wordpress with this structure ?

header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php

    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu' ) );

?>
```

Comment: I'm not a WordPress user really, but there is a stack http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ that is really helpful. Just thought i'd point that out. Although I'm sure someone can answer it on here also

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250866/how-to-add-custom-html-to-wp-nav-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed. Here is the solution:

> functions.php

```
register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu') );

class Menu_With_Description extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' menu-button-bg"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li><hr class="menu-dotted-line"/></li><li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= '<div class="menu-button">' . $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after . '</div>';
        $item_output .= '<div class="menu-button-desc">' . $item->description . '</div>';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

> jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#logo-buttons-bg ul li:last").after("<li><hr class='menu-dotted-line'/></li>");
}
```

> header.php

```
<?php $walker = new Menu_With_Description; ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'walker' => $walker, 'container' => false) ); ?>
```