# How to display a specific image in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, nav

What i am trying to do is display a specific image along with the text returned from wp_nav_menu. I basically want to have images in the background according to the menu option. For example, if the text is `About` then `About.png` will be displayed in the background.  This is easy in PHP but now switching to WordPress, not easy at all.

So far i have accomplished this by putting html of specific images in the Menu Structure>Navigation label.[image]

Is there another way to accomplish this?  I want it to be easy enough that a casual user could upload a different `About.png` into the media library and different image will be shown with the `About` text.  Doing it the way i've done, the user would have to know HTML code.

Here is my wp_nav_menu

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu'));
```

Again, how do i display an image from the media library with the text returned from wp_nav_menu?

If this involves a Custom Walker, could i have an example please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add custom HTML to wp\_nav\_menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250866/how-to-add-custom-html-to-wp-nav-menu)

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079190/add-featured-image-to-wp-nav-menu-items/26079191